# В чем разница "&&" между "&" и "||" между "|" java?

Tags: java, if, битовые-операции

Читал книгу философия ява.
дошёл к пункту:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
какя разница между одинарним и двойним использованием сивволов

```
boolean i,a;
if(a||i){}
if(a|i){}

if(a&&i){}
if(a&i){}
```

Кроме того что `&` это должно бить двое `true`,
а с `|` нужно только одно `true`.

Comment: Если `a == true`, то остальное в записи `a || b` не будет проверяться.

Comment: В данном случае никакой разницы. Точнее, она не принципиальна.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще, `&` и `|` - побитовые операторы, а `&&` и `||` - логические.

В случае с `boolean` типами в вашем примере нет разницы принципиальной. В общем случае при использовании `&` или `|` на `boolean` правая часть выражения будет вычисляться независимо от того, какое значение у левой части выражения.

К примеру, если бы там были не просто переменные, а метод, скажем:

```
private boolean additionalCheck() {
    // делаем что-то
    // к примеру, меняем глобальное состояние
    return true;
}
```

То между `if(a||additionalCheck()){}` и `if(a|additionalCheck()){}` будет разница, если `a` равно `true`.

В первом случае `additionalCheck()` вообще не вызовется, т.к. `a` уже `true` и нет смысла проверять другие условия. А вот втором случае `additionalCheck()` вызовется независимо от значения `a`.

Если у вас в `additionalCheck()` специфичная логика, к примеру, меняющая глобальное состояние, то нужно с умом выбирать, что использовать - `|`/`&` или `||`/`&&`.

Comment: `bool` - это не есть `JAVA`!

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець и то верно, спасибо.